# Keycloak Authentication Flow: It is possible to disable a required action for a specific flow?

Tags: keycloak

I have developed my own extension for keycloak that allows you to log in using a barcode.
This is the flow for it:

[image: BarcodeFlow]

Under Authentication -> Required actions you can define the actions that should be allowed for the flows.
But now I have the problem that I want to disable the action "Update Password" for the barcode login, so that this prompt does not appear in the flow. For the other login flows, however, the action should remain.

Now to my question:
Is it possible to disable the required actions for certain flows? Or do I have to include them in the programmed extension somehow?

Important: I am aware that you can disable the required actions, but they should only be disabled for a specific flow.